# Error: Column *** already belongs to another dataTable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am try to filter some data and add to another datatable. While Run time the Error is shows

```
Column *** already belongs to another dataTable
```

**Here My code:**

```
Private Function FilterbyMode(ByVal FullTable As DataTable, ByVal Mode As String) As DataTable
    Dim Result As New DataTable(), i As Integer, j As Integer
    Try
        i = 0
        j = 0
        With FullTable
            Result.Clear()
            Result.Columns.Clear()
            For i = 0 To .Columns.Count - 1
                Result.Columns.Add(.Columns(i))
            Next
            For i = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1
                If .Rows(i)(5).ToString = Mode Then
                    Result.Rows.Add(.Rows(i))
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        lobjGeneral.Err_Handler("Reports", "LoadGrid", Err.Description, "Reports.aspx")
    End Try
    FilterbyMode = Result
End Function
```

What is my issue? Any one give me solution..

Comment: You can use the **Clone()** method to make the other table and then use **ImportRow()** method for your concerned rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
Result = FullTable.Clone(); //replicate the structure
```

And then

```
If .Rows(i)(5).ToString == Mode Then // i belive you need comparison
      Result.ImportRow(.Rows(i)); // Add this row
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can`t add column from dataTable to another dataTable because if it will copy by ref and if you will change the column in one datatable it will change in the other as well...
What you can do is to clone the column to new object and add the new object to the new datatable.

Comment: Good information. Keep in mind the Clone function will create a new object in memory so you may have to cast it back to the original type. Additionally, be sure to dispose of the old object if it is not needed. lastly, the GetChanges function is quite useful as it also creates a new object in memory but only returns the affected records.